# Rotated figure moves to the right of the document

Tags: subfloats, ieeetran, tikz-3dplot

I want to rotate a 3d solid using tikz-3dplot within a subfigure environment (I am using IEEEtran document class as well).
When I perform the rotation, the figure rotates as expected but moves to the extreme right of a column (in a 2-column document).
For example, I have a subfigure matrix {a b \ c d} in a column. If I want to plot the figure on the position c, it overwrites on the right of position d.
Is there any advice to correct that problem.

```
\subfigure[$\xi$]{
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{125}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{0}{0}{10}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        [ %tdplot_main_coords,
          tdplot_rotated_coords,
          cube/.style={very thick,black},
            grid/.style={very thin,gray},
            axis/.style={-latex,black,thin}]


    %draw the axes
    \draw[axis,tdplot_main_coords] (0,0,0) -- (1.2,0,0) node[anchor=east]{$\xi_{1}$};
    \draw[axis,tdplot_main_coords] (0,0,0) -- (0,1.2,0) node[anchor=west]{$\xi_{2}$};
    \draw[axis,tdplot_main_coords] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[anchor=west]{$\xi_{3}$};

    %draw the top and bottom of the cube
    \draw[cube] (0,0,0) -- (-0.2,0.3464,0.4) -- (-0.4,0,0.8);
    \draw[cube,dotted] (-0.4,0,0.8) -- (-0.2,-0.3464,0.4) -- (0,0,0);
    \draw[cube] (0.4,0,0.4) -- (0.2,0.3464,0.8) -- (0,0,1.2) -- (0.2,-0.3464,0.8) -- cycle;

    %draw the edges of the cube
    \draw[cube] (0,0,0) -- (0.4,0,0.4);
    \draw[cube] (-0.2,0.3464,0.4) -- (0.2,0.3464,0.8);
    \draw[cube] (-0.4,0,0.8) -- (0,0,1.2);
    \draw[cube,dotted] (-0.2,-0.3464,0.4) -- (0.2,-0.3464,0.8);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
```

Comment: All you have to do is move the \tdplotsetrotatedcoords inside the tikzpicture.